# Animated sprite delay, when switching left to right

Tags: javascript, animation

I have this sprite that animates well enough, but when you use the arrow keys to switch between left and right, sometimes there is a slight delay and he stops for a split second before turning.

**UPDATE:** It seems that it is most easily recreated by switching left and right with their being a split second overlap where both keys are being held down at the same time.

Does it have to do with the interval not clearing correctly? Is it a performance bottleneck? Is my order of operations wrong for instantiating the animation?

Any ideas as to why?

Here is the code for the page, just run the snippet and use your arrow keys left and right to make him animate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var character = document.getElementById("character");
  var characterPosition = 0;
  var yOffset = 0;
  var runningInterval;
  var isRunning = false;

  function startRun() {
    isRunning = true;
    characterPosition = 0;
    yOffset = 0;
    runningInterval = setInterval(animateRun, 40);
  }

  function animateRun() {
    var newPosition = characterPosition - 200;

    if (newPosition == -1800 && yOffset == 0) {
      newPosition = 0;
      yOffset = -199.33;
    }

    if (newPosition == -1800 && yOffset == -199.33) {
      newPosition = 0;
      yOffset = -398.66;
    }

    if (newPosition == -1200 && yOffset == -398.66) {
      newPosition = 0;
      yOffset = 0;
    }

    character.style.backgroundPosition = newPosition + "px" + " " + yOffset + "px";
    characterPosition = newPosition;
  }

  function stopRun() {
    isRunning = false;
    clearInterval(runningInterval);
  }

  $("body").on("keydown", function(event) {
    // left
    if (!isRunning) {
      if (event.which == 37) {
        $("#character").css("transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        startRun();
      }

      //right
      if (event.which == 39) {
        $("#character").css("transform", "scaleX(1)");
        startRun();
      }
    }
  });

  $("body").on("keyup", function() {
    stopRun();
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#character {
  width: 200px;
  height: 199.33px;
  background-image: url("https://rebootcreate.com/games/testing/assets/braid-run-sprite.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Animation Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="character"></div>
</body>
</html>
```